# How does the identity operator in JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript, boolean, comparison-operators

Why does `(9 > 8) === true` result in "`true`" but `(10>9>8) === true` results in "`false`"?

Comment: your statement is not valid (10>9>8) is compiled to ((10>9)>8) which is (true>8). true is suggested with 1 in js. (1>8) is false

Comment: first: (true)===true second:(true>8)===true -> true - converted to 1, 1>8 = false, false===true -> false. I think.... :)

Answer (score 7):

If we see both, the JavaScript executes from left to right. As we all know:

```
(9 > 8) === true
```

The above statement is indeed true. But what we need to know is, how JavaScript executes this. If we see how it gets executed, the execution steps are as below:

```
(10 > 9 > 8) === true
((10 > 9) > 8) === true
(true > 8) === true
(1 > 8) === true
false === true
false
```

Answer (score 3):

Because:

```
10 > 9 > 8 === (true) > 8
```

Which is false. In *truthy* values, a true gets expressed as "1". Since `true > 0` and `false < 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You should only have one comparative operator without using the AND(&&) or the OR(||) operators.

If you want (10>9>8) to resolve to true, you would format it like this:

(10 > 9 && 9 > 8)

this says "check 10 > 9, if that's true, check 9 > 8. If they're both true, return true"